# Scala: Have the type parameter of a collection survive a "collect" when the type parameter is a member type

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-parameter, partialfunction

Normally, when collecting all the elements of a sequence that match a particular type, the resulting collection has both the type of the original collection and the type selected for:

```
trait Foo
trait Bar

trait Baz {
  // Works
  def def1(foo: Seq[Foo]): Seq[Foo with Bar] = 
    foo collect {case foobar: Bar => foobar}
}
```

This even works when the the input type is parameterized by a bounded member type and all I want back is a sequence parameterized by the bound type (not the member type):

```
trait Baz {
  type memberType <: Foo

  // Works
  def2(foo: Seq[memberType]): Seq[Foo with Bar] =
    foo collect {case foobar: Bar => foobar}
}
```

However, this fails when I actually want back a sequence parameterized by the member type:

```
trait Baz {
  type memberType <: Foo

  // Fails
  def def3(foo: Seq[memberType]): Seq[memberType with Bar] =
    foo collect {case foobar: Bar => foobar}
}
```

Error message:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[this.Foo with this.Bar]
 required: Seq[Baz.this.memberType with this.Bar]
    foo collect {case foobar: Bar => foobar}
```

To recover functionality, I can include the member type in the `collect` call, but that seems redundant given that every element has to match that type because of the signature:

```
trait Baz {
  type memberType <: Foo

  // Works
  def def4(foo: Seq[memberType]): Seq[memberType with Bar] =
    foo collect {case foobar: memberType with Bar => foobar}
}
```

Is there a way to define a sequence of member types so that they remember their member types when `collect`ed?

Comment: Have checked that code for warnings? Since `memberType` is abstract, it is erased in the `foobar: memberType with Bar` check.

Comment: I'm slightly confused why 1 and 2 even work. The collected sequence is just a Seq[Bar] but the compiler still allows it to be typed as a Seq[Foo with Bar].
Okay I guess I'm more confused why this doesn't result in an erasure warning.

Comment: I see no warnings when I run any of the working examples. Would type erasure have any effect on the last example (which has been edited to correctly indicate that it "Works")?

Comment: That's quite odd but it does show the warnings if you turn Baz into a class.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answer, but just some observation. This works:

```
trait Baz[A <: Foo] {
  def def3(foo: Seq[A]): Seq[A] =
    foo collect {case foobar => foobar}
}
```

but this not:

```
trait Baz[A <: Foo] {
  def def3(foo: Seq[A]): Seq[A] =
    foo collect {case foobar: Bar => foobar}
}
```

also this not:

```
trait Baz[A] {
  def def3(foo: Seq[A]): Seq[A] =
    foo collect {case foobar: Bar => foobar}
}
```

so it seems to be an effect of the pattern matcher; I don't think it has anything to do with `collect` in particular. Somehow it looses information as soon as you add the type to the match case :-/

But as Kaito, I was actually surprised, too, that your first two cases *did* work. It must be (and seems reasonable) that the type inference algorithm makes a difference between a known stable type (`Foo`) and a type parameter or type member. You might need to ask on the scala language mailing list to get some of the compiler gurus to answer the question...